# Decrease CPU usage while rotating image in QML

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I created a QML application based on `Qt 5.2` that I deploy on Mac OS X and Windows (from XP to 8). My application has one main animation which rotates an image indefinitely while the user is live on air. This animation is a core part of the application and I cannot remove it.

Rotating the image takes too much CPU power and I am looking for a way to fix this. The reason behind it is that *lots* of users are not supporting OpenGL 2 (on Windows) and I will have to rely on MESA's DLL to do the rendering in software, making the application unusable on these machines while the animation is running.

Here is my current implementation of the Animation in QML:

```
Image {
  id: imgBroadcastState
  source: "images/broadcast_button.png"
  anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

  NumberAnimation on rotation {
    from: 0
    to: 360
    running: rootWindow.isBroadcasting
    loops: Animation.Infinite
    duration: 7000

    onRunningChanged:{
      if(!running) {
        imgBroadcastState.rotation = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first solution I tried was creating a huge sprite containing all the frames for my animation that I then loaded with [AnimatedSprite](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-animatedsprite.html). This decreased CPU but clearly not enough and more than tripled the RAM consumption, up to 300MB which is not a good solution for old Windows XP machine.

I also tried subclassing [QQuickPaintedItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qquickpainteditem.html) and manually call `paint()` every 30ms (with a `QTimer`) to rotate the image. This also decreases CPU but not enough either. Here is the code I used:

```
void MXPaintedItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
  QTransform rot;
  rot.rotate(m_angle);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
  painter->translate(width() / 2, height() / 2);
  painter->rotate(m_angle);
  // Use preloaded QImage
  painter->drawImage(QPoint(-width() / 2, -height() / 2), m_image);


  m_angle += 2.5;
}
```

Is there any way to improve on this and decrease the CPU usage of rotation animations?

**EDIT**:

Of course I could change the animation or not use one but this is not a long term solution. In the end this image will have to be drawn/updated dynamically to reflect a VUMeter and represent the sound level. So I need to find a proper solution allowing me to update part of a QML view in real-time without having to redraw the whole UI and take so much CPU.

**EDIT2**:
I've discovered that the main CPU usage is not the rotation itself but the fact that it then has to redraw the whole UI everytime. You can make sure of this by just calling `return` in the `paint()` function instead of rotating anything. The CPU usage is the same doing this compared to animating the image itself which shows that the issue comes from updating the whole UI everytime one of the QML components in the scene is updated

Comment: Why are you using Mesa? Have you [looked](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL) at [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/)?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using ANGLE but it is not supported on XP and then works only on half of my clients machine and even with ANGLE I get some users with empty frames when starting the app on other Windows machines

Comment: You need a custom `QML` component then. It will generate all the needed rotations in advance, store them in memory and you'll simply play them back when needed, take advantage of symmetry perhaps...

Comment: Wow, that must be some old machines. Well it seams that QtQuick 2.0 is not for you. Don't know if you try use QtQuick 1.0 (It's avaible as a plugin), and if it still works as in Qt4.8, it should run faster on CPU then OpenGL on Mesa.

Comment: Arpegius >  Going back to QtQuick 1.0 after 6 months of development on QtQuick 2.0/QtQuick.Controls is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: user1095108 > This won't change anything, it is not the rotation that takes CPU it is the paint event itself.

Comment: @koopajah from a quick computation you need `4.8` rotations per second. which means your paint should rotate only after `250ms` . which is not displayed in your code

Comment: UmNyobe > Why is that? Is it moving for just 1 degree? Because if I do as you say then the animation clearly "lags". You need to move at least 30 times per seconds to have an animation running smoothly. The angle of 2.5 is just an example here

Comment: @koopajah Could you post the image you are working with or something that might be closely similar? It may help to show some optimizations in the animation.

Comment: The CPU usage is the same whatever the image you take, even drawing basic Rectangle and rotating it takes almost as much CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating even more I have reached the conclusion that there is no easy way to optimize this. The best performance would be obtained through QML itself because it is optimized for caching elements and improving the scene repainting.

The main solution would be to repaint only part of a scene. This is not yet possible with QML and the new SceneGraph rendering and is not planned in the near future. This answer has been given to me by the people in charge of the development of this feature in Qt.

The CPU usage itself comes is highly dependent on the hardware and the graphic card drivers because everything is now based on OpenGL 2.0 and rely on the fact that your hardware/drivers properly support some OpenGL operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the memory space and the number of rotations is small, use one bitmap for each rotation.  This is how "spinners" have been written since the beginning of computers.

The theory is that a bitblit is faster than performing a rotation transformation, then blitting the resulting image.

Comment: Isn't this the same as creating a sprite and loading it in `AnimatedSprite` which I already tried? Part of the issue is that a full rotation takes 7seconds and I need at least 30 fps (under you really see it lag) which leads to 210 frames in the same sprite so using at least 250MB of extra memory but still too much CPU. Part of the issue is that everytime the frame changes it needs to redraw the whole scene which costs too much.

Comment: @koopajah There is no way you should need that many frames. Lets talk about a simple example, say a 'progress wheel' (google it). You should be able to create a similar animation with a low number of frames maybe 12-ish maybe a bit more depending on the complexity.

Comment: @koopajah Or why not explore other options to simply your problem? What about a big bright red button that says on air? That's pretty standard to be displayed outside of a radio room why not show it on your UI? Or maybe just a blinking red animation similar to how a recorder shows it? Those both would greatly simplify things for you.

Comment: Because that animation is a core part of our application/branding and removing it just because it takes too much CPU on a computer seems a bit insane. And for the number of frames I don't see how I can rotate an image with only 12 frames without it lagging except if it rotates more than once in a second of course which is not my case. Also this is not the only animation we plan to have in the app so we are looking for a long term solution not just a hack for this one.

Comment: @koopajah, you are right. For a suggestion (for animating some frame per second such as 12fps), you can use a `Timer` and increase `rotation` property of your image by 30 (divide 360 by 12) in `onTrigger` event handler. It will decrease CPU usage dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Next I would try taking your animation and producing an animated GIF. Whatever tool you use to produce the gif should provide you with an ability to configure the compression/optimizations to get a quality/size that you're happy with.

Then try using the QML [AnimatedImage Element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-animatedimage.html) to display the GIF, perhaps that will provide better results.

Comment: One of the first solutions I've tried but this takes as much CPU as the NumberAnimation